# Stratified Shuffle Split for large files

Tags: python, split, scikit-learn, large-data

I have a CSV file of 35GB (expected in future to be larger) for a binary classification problem in Keras. To train and test my model I want to split the data into train/test datasets having the same proportion of positive samples in each one. Something like this:

```
|Dataset type | Total samples | negative samples | positive instances |
|-------------|---------------|------------------|--------------------|
|Dataset      |    10000      |        8000      |       2000         |
|Train        |    7000       |        6000      |       1000         |
|Test         |    3000       |        2000      |       1000         |
```

As this dataset is too large to fit into memory, I created a custom generator to load the data in batch and to train the model via `fit_generator`. Therefore, I cannot apply the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` method from Scikitlearn to do this as it needs the entire dataset, instead of only a portion of the data, to keep the proportion of positive instances of both train and test datasets.

Edit: My data has the following shape: 11500 x 160000

Does anyone know how could I do what I want?

### Solution

I followed Ian Lin's answer stet by step. Just note that if you have a large number of columns, converting a Dataframe into hdf5 may fail. Thus, create the hdf5 file directly from a numpy array

Also, to append data to an hdf5 file I had to do the following (set `maxshape=None` to every dimension of your dataset which you want to resize without limits. In my case, I resize the dataset to append unlimited rows with a fixed column number):

```
path = 'test.h5'
mydata = np.random.rand(11500, 160000)
if not os.path.exists(path):
    h5py.File(path, 'w').create_dataset('dataset', data=mydata, maxshape=(None, mydata.shape[1]))
else:
    with h5py.File(path, 'a') as hf:
        hf['dataset'].resize(hf['dataset'].shape[0] + mydata.shape[0], axis=0)
        hf["dataset"][-mydata.shape[0]:, :] = mydata
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do this:

1. store the data into a file like [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) or HDF5 dataset (If your dataset has a large number of features, use [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) instead of `pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf()` or pytables)
2. generate an integer index using something like this `range(dataset.shape[0])`
3. use the split function in sklearn to split the integer index into train/test
4. pass the integer index into your generator, and use the integer index to find the data in the [h5py.Dataset](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#Dataset) or [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

If you are using `keras.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow()` as the generator, you can refer to a helper I wrote [here](https://github.com/ianlini/serialtime#dataset-wrapper) to reindex the data easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ian Lin. However, converting my csv file into HDF5 did not work as it is too large. It is worth mentioning that my dataset contains 11500 samples and 160000 features (they are not images), that is, 11500x160000 matrix. 'too large header' exception is raised.

Comment: 11500x160000 is actually quite small. I think the max size of a dimension in HDF5 is `2^64`. How did you do that? I can easily create a file that has that large of dimension using `h5py`: `h5py.File('test.h5', 'w').create_dataset('test', data=np.random.rand(11500, 160000))`

Comment: I tried to create it using `df.to_hdf('test.h5, 'w', formar='table')`. Note that I need a non-fixed dataset because to create it I append data from multiple batches. I read there is no problem to do this when `format='fixed'` (default value). After the first iteration, I use `df.to_hdf(path, append=True)` to append data to the existing file.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a limitation of `pandas`, so I suggest you use `h5py` instead of `pandas` (`pytables`). If you use `h5py`, you can create the dataset first because you already know the dimensions. After creation, just fill the rows from multiple batches.

Comment: I've done what you suggested and now it works fine! I will update my question to put my solution so as it can help other people.